# Posição de um elemento do vetor em PORTUGOL

Tags: array, portugol, portugol-studio

Gostaria de encontrar a POSIÇÃO do MAIOR ELEMENTO.

Fiz um `contador++` dentro da estrutura condicional SE, no entanto, não está correta a posição.

O enunciado da questão é essa:

> Faça um programa que leia N números reais e armazene-os em um vetor. Em seguida, mostrar na tela o maior número do vetor (supor não haver empates). Mostrar também a posição do maior elemento,  considerando a primeira posição como 0 (zero).

Meu código está assim:

```
programa
{
    
    funcao inicio()
    {
        real qtdElementos, v[100], maiorElemento = 0.0, posicaoElemento = 0.0, contador = 0.0

        v[0] = 0.0
        escreva("Quantos números você vai digitar? ")
        leia(qtdElementos)
            
        para(inteiro a = 1; a <= qtdElementos; a++){
            escreva("Digite um número: ")
            leia(v[a])
            
            maiorElemento = v[0]
        
            para(inteiro b = 1; b <= qtdElementos; b++){
                se(v[b] > maiorElemento){
                    maiorElemento = v[b]
                    contador++
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    
        escreva("MAIOR VALOR: ", maiorElemento) 
        escreva("\nPOSIÇÃO DO MAIOR VALOR: ", contador) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verificando seu código o contador esta apenas somando, e não retornando a real posição do maior número, se você verificar o seu próprio código no seu segundo loop de repetição você pode armazenar a posição correta do maior numero fazendo assim

- contador = b

seu código vai ficar assim

```
funcao inicio() {
     real qtdElementos, v[100], maiorElemento = 0.0, posicaoElemento = 0.0, contador = 0.0

    v[0] = 0.0
    escreva("Quantos números você vai digitar? ")
    leia(qtdElementos)
        
    para(inteiro a = 1; a <= qtdElementos; a++){
        escreva("Digite um número: ")
        leia(v[a])
        
        maiorElemento = v[0]
    
        para(inteiro b = 1; b <= qtdElementos; b++){
            se(v[b] > maiorElemento){
                maiorElemento = v[b]   
                contador  = b        //armazenando a posição do maior valor
            }
            
        }
        
    }

    escreva("MAIOR VALOR: ", maiorElemento) 
    escreva("\nPOSIÇÃO DO MAIOR VALOR: ", contador) 
  }
```

Uma dica seria mudar o nome dessa variável para "posicao" assim é uma boa prática de programação ;)

Comment: Muito obrigada Diego, compreendi meu erro! Você me ajudou muito, obrigada pelo toque, vou alterar o nome da variável.